# -[UIViewController setSelectedRowTitle:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x13fab360

Tags: uitableview, cell, segue, custom-cell

I am trying to pass data from one table view Cell to next UIViewController . I am using Navigation Controller also , But when i am clicking Cell then it giving error :-

```
-[UIViewController setSelectedRowTitle:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x13fab360
```

my **prepareForSegue** code which i used go next with data is:-

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [NearBy_PlacesArray count];
}


-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *TableIdentifire = @"NearMe";

    NearByTableViewCell *cell = (NearByTableViewCell*)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:TableIdentifire];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[NearByTableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:TableIdentifire];

    }

    NearByPlace *nearBy = [NearBy_PlacesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.NearBy_Thumbnail_Image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:nearBy.NearByImageName];
    cell.NearBy_TitleLabel.text = nearBy.NearByPlaceName;
    cell.NearBy_NoLabel.text = nearBy.NearByPlace_no;


    return cell;
}
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ShowNearByPlaces"])
    {


        NSIndexPath *indexPath = nil;
        NearByPlace *nearPlace = nil;

            indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
            nearPlace = [NearBy_PlacesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        NSLog(@"indexPath-- %@ \n" , indexPath);
        NSLog(@"recipe-- %@ \n " , nearPlace);


        nearByPlaceDetail_ViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;

        destViewController.SelectedRowTitle = nearPlace;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Mantosh, you can simply do this :

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

  {
      static NSString *aStrIdentifier = @"cell";
      UITableViewCell *aCell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:aStrIdentifier];

  ```
  UILabel *aLblPlaceName=(UILabel*)[aCell viewWithTag:1];
  aLblPlaceName.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [arrPlaces objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

  return aCell;
  ```

  }
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

  {
      strStoreValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [arrPlaces objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
      [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"detailViewSegue" sender:self];
  }
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender

  {
      DetailViewController *aObjDetailVC = segue.destinationViewController;
      aObjDetailVC.strPlace = strStoreValue;
  }